# Java DecimalFormat class and E-notation

Tags: java

I'm attempting to learn Java(I have novice level programming experience in other languages) and am currently reading Absolute Java 5th Edition. Everything is smooth sailing so far except for a small bit related to the DecimalFormat class as it relates to E-notation. I understand the basics but some of the logic I just can't seem to "get".

For example, the number 12345 formatted with ##0.##E0 ends up as 12.3E3 according to the book. Why did it determine that there are two digits before the decimal instead of, say, one or three? I know the # is an optional digit, but it after playing with some formatting constraints on different numbers it almost seems like the formatting is somewhat arbitrary(although I know it can't be). I've searched for a good explanation outside of the book and have come up short. If someone could "dumb it down" for me I would be really appreciative.

Also, how often is this type of formatting used in real world application?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is the number of # in the front part of the pattern, thus if it was `#0.##E0` it will be `1.234E4`

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.##E0");
System.out.println(df.format(12345));
```

The best way to learn a new language if to write little test programs like this.

Also read more on [the Oracle site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Comment: This sentence on the Oracle site "If the maximum number of integer digits is greater than their minimum number and greater than 1" is a bit confusing for some reason. Could you possibly make it a bit more clear?

Comment: Nevermind, I just figured it out I believe. Shew, my brain isn't firing on all pistons it seems, haha. Thanks for the help!